# Toggle switch does not maintain state after application restart

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am using a Toggle switch that works fine until I restart the application. After restarting the app, the toggle switch does not maintain the previous changes and reverts to the default state. How can I fix this?

UPDATE: This is how I tried to save the toggle switch value to local setting.

```
private void ThemeToggle_switch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (ThemeToggle.IsOn)
        {
            (Frame).RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["ThemeToggle"] = "Light";
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["ThemeToggleValue"] = "on";


        }
        else (Frame).RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["ThemeToggle"] = "Dark";

        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["ThemeToggleValue"] = "off";

    }
```

In App.xamls.cs, I have set the local settings values as follows:

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["ThemeToggle"] = "Dark";
localSettings.Values["ThemeToggleValue"] = "off";
```

The logic works fine, toggle switch is working, theme is getting changed. However, as soon as I close and restart the app, my app DOES maintain the selected theme, but the toggle button does not maintain its state. This is how my Xaml code looks like:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Uid="ThemeToggle"  x:Name="ThemeToggle" OnContent="Dark Theme" OffContent="Light Theme" Toggled="ThemeToggle_switch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,20,6,10" Height="65"/>
```

I suspect that this might something to do with adding/replacing/reading the values to/from local settings, but I am clueless on how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Once you lauch your app and UI is created, you decide what states controls have. If you haven't saved somewhere the previous state of your switch (for example in *LocalSettings*) then it will always have default value. The easiest way probably is to use settings for this, maybe use *TwoWay* binding to get/set the value of suitable property.

Comment: @Romasz: It looks like the changes made by the switch does persist after app restart, but not the switch state.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question - please specify it better, put some code what you have tried. Also ensure that you are talking about app restart/suspension/other.

Comment: Here's what I have tried so far: 

     private void ThemeToggle_switch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ThemeToggle.IsOn)
            {
                (Frame).RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
                        }
            else (Frame).RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
                 }

When I toggle the switch, the app theme changes perfectly. On restarting the app maintains the modified theme, but the Toggle switch does not. It reverts to its default value, which is off. I want the Toggle switch to maintain its state to reflect the  selected theme.

Comment: Bind IsOn preperty to property which will load/save from *LocalSettings*, use two-way binding, also using suitable converter may be needed.

Comment: @Romasz: I added more information. Can you please take a look and let me know if you can help me fix this issue?

Comment: One way is to write a code in page's constructor (after initializecomponent) that will set walue of your toggle switch - something like: `toggleswitch.IsOn = valueFromSettings == defaultIsOnValue`.